# Which one is correct? $(\log a)^{x+1} = (x+1)\log a$ OR $(\log x)^{a+1} = (a+1)\log x $

Tags: logarithms

According to log property 
$$(\log m)^n = n(\log m)$$

Which one is correct? $$(\log a)^{x+1} = (x+1)\log a$$ OR $$(\log x)^{a+1} = (a+1)\log x $$

Comment: Nope! The property is actually $$\log(\color{blue}{m^n}) = \color{blue} n\log(\color{blue} m)$$

Comment: Neither is correct.

Comment: If you had intended on writing $\log a^x+1$, then you'd get $x\log a+1$.

Comment: Ak19 yes ......

Comment: Andrew Chin According to me one of them may be right......please explain me why neither of them are correct

Comment: I m not satisfied with anyone of the answer.....please explain my question in details

Comment: Do you mean $(\log a)^{x+1}$ or $(\log a)^x+1$? And if one of your expressions is wrong, the ther one is wrong too, just swap $a$ and $x$.

Comment: According to the rest of us, neither is correct as all you have done is switch the position of the variables $a$ and $x$.  To get more out of this community, please edit your question to explain your own thinking.

Comment: You should use LaTeX to prevent this kind of misunderstandings. I've tried to edit.

Comment: Celio Augusto  it is (log a)^x+1 .....and to avoid confusion the first part of ur comment...do u mean (log a)^ x+1

Comment: Don’t you suppose you could try it with some chosen numbers for $a$ and $x$ ?

Comment: Lubin is (log a)^x+1 = x+1(log a )  is correct?or (log x)^a+1 = a+1(log x) is correct ?

Comment: You should use LaTeX, and parentheses (where needed), and also use superscripts correctly, to prevent this kind of misunderstanding. Do you mean $((\log a)^x)+1$ or $(\log a)^{x+1}$ or $\log(a^{x+1})$? Only the last of these is equal to $(x+1)\log a$.

Comment: Rosie F Read my question .....it has two question ....among two of them which one is correct question no 1 is (log a) ^x+1 = x+1 (log a)   Is my answer x+1 (log a) is correct ?  And question no 2 is (log x)^a+1 = a+1(log x)  is my answer a+1(log x) is correct ? Now tell me which one is correct from 1 and 2 and why